# Calculating points on the curve

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone, coronasdk

Is it possible to calculate intermediate points of a curve...Here is my mirror image

[image]

In the above image.Is it possible to calculate the intermediate points(one side)  by knowing starting and ending point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know something about the curve it is, and it all depends on what you know about the curve (start and end points, initial slopes, center points, etc).  There are generally two approaches:

1. If you know the equation of the curve, it's possible to do this exactly.  Commonly curves like this are either circles or [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), and if you know it's either of these, you can fit all the other points exactly just given a few.
2. You can also do a [cubic spline fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29).  This is a standard approach to fitting smooth curves so packages to do this are very common.  On a smooth curve like this, give then end points, and, say, the middle point, the fit will be almost exact.  (Here, you essentially end up with a Bezier curve, though parametrized a bit differently.)

Comment: +1 for beziers. They are the most awesome programmable curves ever, on and off the screen.